# Difuran Synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

We've been asked for the mechanism for the synthesis of the following difuran from the starting materials shown below:

[image]

The ytterbium complex will act as a Lewis acid and activate the oxygen of the benzaldehyde. However, I don't know what the next step in the mechanism would be.

Comment: Electrophilic aromatic substitution?

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a series of two electrophilic aromatic substitutions. The ytterbium stabilizes the benzyl cation enough for it to attack position 5 of the 2-methylfuran. After the new ytterbium complex dissociates away, the resulting cation can then attack another 2-methylfuran, and the final product is formed.

[image: mechanism]